# Embedded linux bitbake - how to extract source of u-boot

Tags: beagleboard, u-boot

Following the instructions on

http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/building-angstrom

I did a $bitbake u-boot -c configure

It downloaded the sources and patches of u-boot for beagleboard. I want to make changes to the u-boot code. How do I extract the u-boot source along with the applied patches from bitbake ?

Inside the folder

build/tmp-angstrom_v2012_05-eglibc/work/beagleboard-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-2011.12-r8

Inside that there is a 'git' folder that contains the u-boot source. There is also a folder called 2011.12 that has patches. I dont know whether the patches are already applied or which patches to apply, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice set of steps found here: http://elinux.org/EBC_Exercise_15_Configuring_U-boot.  This is Exercise 13, and you may need to look at Exercise 12 as well.

Good luck.